# Enumerate package won't accept my labels

Tags: enumerate

I'm typing, and I copied all my "preamble" (all the code that comes before \begin{document}) straight from another document, call it document A, to another document B. I type something like

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item stuff 
\item stuff
\end{enumerate}
```

in document A, and it runs just fine. I copy-paste the same piece into document B and get an error message "Missing number, treated as zero". I just don't understand why it works fine in one document and not another, despite both having the same packages and all that.

Also, I'm not very familiar with the ins and outs of LaTeX, so apologies in advance if this is just a really silly question.

Comment: the syntax you show is not defined by the `enumerate` package.  It is from the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then how come it works in one document and not another?

Comment: Because one document uses `enumitem` and the other does not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. Thanks!

Comment: when asking for help with an error message it always helps if you provide a complete small document that reproduces the error, as in my answer.

Comment: given that I wrote `enumerate` and didn't define that syntax, i had a suspicion that I might be right here:-)

Answer (score 5):

This is `enumitem` package syntax and is not defined by the `enumerate` package.

This runs without error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item stuff 
\item stuff
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```